# Is it safe to have 32-bit libs in 64-bit Linux?

Tags: linux, 64-bit, fedora, 32-bit, libraries

I am running Fedora 16 x86-64.

Wanting to run some games that were released for 32-bit Linux, I've installed the 32-bit versions of the required libraries. Works very well.

My question is; In the long run, would it hurt my computer to have the 32-bit libs installed alongside the 64-bit libs? Would it in any way inhibit the use of any program or feature of the operating system?

I'm just curious, but I've been reading on the internet that having 32-bit libs installed on a 64-bit system should be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't run into issues most of the time time. However, you may experience yum install errors caused when trying to install a newer 32-bit package along an existing older 64-bit package on your system:

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/share/doc/glibc-2.12.90/NEWS from install of glibc-2.12.90-21.i686 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.12.90-17.x86_64
```

If you run into such an error, make sure to run *yum update* first, so that the 64-bit package is updated to the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

There's no problem with having 32-bit libraries installed, unless you're extremely low on disk space of course.